# How to add permission to com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider uri content://com.sec.badge/apps in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Am getting below error on my Samsung phone running android 10. I have been try to fix this for days now and no luck.

I have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
```

to my AndroidManifest file and no luck still.
I would appreciate your help.

```
{Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider 
uri content://com.sec.badge/apps from pid=30440, uid=10440 requires 
com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE, or grantUriPermission()
at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualIntMethod 
(Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, 
Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0008e] in 
<8b3b636835d84984ba4604c1f57b1983>:0
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualInt32Method (System.String 
encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] 
in <8b3b636835d84984ba4604c1f57b1983>:0
at Android.Content.ContentResolver.Update (Android.Net.Uri uri, Android.Content.ContentValues values, 
System.String where, System.String[] selectionArgs) [0x0008e] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0
```

Thanks in anticipation